# Old top bar site icons are too big in chat lobby

Tags: bug, chat, stack-exchange-button, favicon

It must be tough for the old top bar to see its young replacement thriving. Still, it's not a reason to misbehave like this:

> [image]

Can the rebel icons be shrinked back to their normal size?

Happens in chat lobby of any site (e.g. [lobby for Stack Overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)) and worth to mention the icons are fine in the old top bar at https://stackexchange.com/ itself.

Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m here but doubt it's browser related.

Comment: Repro-ed on IE11 and Safari 5.1.7 but **not** on FireFox 27 (win7.x64)!

Comment: @rene hmm... same machine for all browsers? Firefox has nasty feature of "auto zoom" based on screen resolution maybe this time it actually got useful. :)

Comment: I rechecked on a different box (same os though) repro in Chrome but not on FF.

Comment: Reproduced (IE 10 on Win RT).

Comment: Why can't we just have the new top bar in chat?

Comment: @Seth It's coming in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed as a side effect of deploying the new top bar to chat.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that those icon images are directly linking to each site's [favicon](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) file.  These favicons are [.ico files](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) that contain two distinct icon sizes: a small 16×16 pixel icon and a larger 32×32 pixel one.

Since the `<img>` tag used to load them doesn't specify an explicit size, browsers are free to choose which icon size they'll display.  Those that happen to choose the smaller one (Firefox, Opera) look good, while those that pick the larger one (IE, Chrome) look awkward.

A simple CSS fix would be to force the image size down to 16×16 px, e.g. like this:

```css
.siteFavicon img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

In fact, this is exactly what the main stackexchange.com style sheet does, which is why the bug does not occur there.

Still, this is not the *perfect* fix, since it just scales the larger favicons down.  (The 32×32 px icons sometimes look a bit different from the 16×16 px ones; for example, the SO favicon has fewer bars in the stack at 16×16 px.)  A better fix would be to change the links to point to PNG images with a known fixed size; an even better fix would be to replace them with CSS sprites, and an *even* better fix, of course, would be to replace the whole chat top bar with the new one we've got here.

Even so, the simple CSS fix above does more or less solve the problem.  While waiting for an official fix, I've added the CSS above to version 1.10 of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).