# "A list of all { } Stack Exchange sites" tooltip shows a different number on the chat page

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips, stack-exchange-button

Hovering over the rightmost icon on the top nav on the main or on the site-meta (as well as Meta SE), shows that there are **179** sites on the network currently:

[image]

But hovering over the Stack Exchange logo (on the leftmost corner of the top nav) on the **chat** page of that site shows a list of **181** sites on the network:

[image]

I manually counted the number of sites in each dropdown and it's **179** in both. Are there really 181 sites, only the list hasn't been updated?

Comment: [proofassistants.se] recently left private beta, and [substrate.se] *might* leave it too as well.

Comment: We never got that number right btw: [How does SE have 233, 119, and 117 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226458/how-does-se-have-233-119-and-117-sites)