# Number of network sites and the Stack Exchange about page

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, statistics, network-statistics

The About page says, "Comprising 173 Q&A communities". It's known that the number of communities shown varies in different places. As of May 2023, so many sites don't make sense to mention a specific number in the description part of the Stack Exchange About page, especially considering that the third and fourth sections of this page have several scorecards.

I first suggest adding a scorecard for **last year's sites** similar to **Monthly Visits** and using that number everywhere.

[image: Montly Visits]

My second suggestion is to add a section with scorecards about sites like Area 51, Stack Apps, Stack Exchange Data Explorer, and Chat. They might be shown at the bottom

---

First section: Title

> ## The world’s largest programming community is growing

Second section: Description

> Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network help people find the answers they need, when they need them. Comprising 173 Q&A communities, including Stack Overflow, over 100 million people visit every month to ask questions, learn, and share technical knowledge. Our products and tools empower people to find what they need to develop technology at work or at home. These products include, Stack Overflow for Teams, Stack Overflow Advertising, Collectives™ on Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow Talent.

Third section: SEN stats

> ###### Past Year On The Stack Exchange Network
>
> |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Monthly Visits 418.8M | Monthly Pageviews 806.3M | Questions Asked 3.1M | Upvotes 23M |
> | Answers Submitted 3.5M | Edits To Improve Post Quality 4.9M | Comments 13.5M | Downvotes 3M |

Fourth section: SO stats

> ###### Stack Overflow Stats
>
> |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Monthly Unique Visitors 51.2M | Monthly Visits 257.7M | Registered Stack Overflow Users 11.7M | Company Pages on Stack Overflow Talent 30.3K |

Suggested new section: Unique site stats

- Stack Exchange Data Explorer

  - Total number of queries
  - Queries created last year
- Area 51:

  - Number of site proposals since the site was launched until the end of last year.
  - Number of beta sites
  - Number of graduated sites
- Stack Apps:

  - Number of apps since the site was launched.
  - Number of scripts since the site was launched.
- Chat:

  - Number of chat servers
  - Total number of users using the chat since it was launched.
  - The average number of users using monthly during the last year.

### Related

- [How does SE have 233, 119, and 117 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226458/1359324)
- ["A list of all { } Stack Exchange sites" tooltip shows a different number on the chat page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377648/1359324)

Comment: FYI, I've already submitted an internal ticket to the devs to update the number of sites as listed on https://stackexchange.com/about to match the actual number of sites – it seems like that number's currently hardcoded on the page (along with the rest of that description paragraph). Ideally, it can be set up so it's automatically updated with the current number of sites.

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks. Having real-time stats will be great. Please consider adding some indicators to let readers know the refresh rate, like a link tooltip, if you don't want to spend too much on dev time. Also, take measures to prevent a bug/glitch from making the page show ridiculous numbers, i.e., set a default value and only show the real-time value if the API response is plausible.

Comment: In the meantime, please consider replacing the current wording, especially if the ticket case will stay in the backlog for a long time. Here is a very rough suggestion: "In 2022, there were n sites. This number will continue to grow during 2023 and the following years" (someone good at copywriting might provide a lot better wording)

Comment: Slightly related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum It's very helpful, but I don't think it should be called "The single source of truth for the site list". In some cases will be better to use the  API. P.S. [Get the Site Display Name from the API](https://stackapps.com/q/337/105187).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to V2Blast for submitting an internal ticket.

In the meantime, there are multiple sources:

- [Community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796) to [How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359794/1359324)
- API, more specifically https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites. Related [Get the Site Display Name from the API](https://stackapps.com/q/337/105187).
- Use web browser features like Find, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and the Javascript console.

In any case, better check out the Community Wiki answer as it mentions special cases that one should have in mind about the different values that could be returned / displayed according to the context and intent.